# Implicit numeric widening for LocalDate.now().plusMonths(m)

Tags: scala, date, intellij-idea

I have this code in an implicit class like this:

```
object TenorOperations {
  implicit class TenorOperations(thiss: Tenor) {

    def toDate: LocalDate = thiss match {
      case Day(d) => LocalDate.now().plusDays(d)
      case Month(m) => LocalDate.now().plusMonths(m)
      case Year(y) => LocalDate.now().plusYears(y)
      case errorDate => throw new Exception("Unexpected date: "+errorDate)
    }

  }
}
```

It just won't compile in IDEA.

```
Error:(14, 47) implicit numeric widening
      case Day(d) => LocalDate.now().plusDays(d)
                                              ^
Error:(15, 51) implicit numeric widening
      case Month(m) => LocalDate.now().plusMonths(m)
                                                  ^
Error:(16, 49) implicit numeric widening
      case Year(y) => LocalDate.now().plusYears(y)
                                                ^
```

This used to work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are `d`,`m` and `y` of type `Int`?

Comment: @Esardes yea they are ints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are using `java.time.LocalDate`, where `LocalDate.plusDays` takes a `Long`, not an `Int`. Normally this will compile perfectly well, unless you both 1) turn on `-Ywarn-numeric-widen` to tell Scala compiler to warn you when widening conversions happen; 2) turn on `-Xfatal-warnings` to make warnings into errors.

You can write `LocalDate.now().plusDays(d.toLong)` (etc) to make the conversions explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about why it happens, but you can try `LocalDate.now().plusMonths(Period.months(m))` (same for days and years).